# How to make grid on list page to be editable?

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to allow editing on form with list page template. I would like to make grid to be editable on default (I know it is against check style).

- The table field property is set to allow edit yes
- The user I am log in with have the right to edit
- The datasource allow edit property is set to yes
- The grid allow edit property is set to yes
- Every column in grid has allow edit yes

I do not change allow edit in code and I am still not able to edit any column.

How I can change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a list page as a copy of `SysBPStyle_ListPage` you do not change the behavior.
List pages are read only by definition.

You may use a simple list or another form template.

Forms started by double clicking on a list page item can be set to edit mode by default.
To do so use the form option dialog:

[image]